# Laravel правильная выборка данных

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет! Есть не разрешенный по LARAVEL, а конкретно выборка данных из БД, уже 2 дня над этой проблемой бьюсь=((( Как выбрать из БД данные за текущий месяц с суммой значений каждого дня(заказов может быть несколько за один день), т.е есть вот такой массив

```
1 => 34$
1 => 34$
2 => 45$
2 => 67$
3 => 12$
3 => 42$
```

а на выходе должно получиться

```
1=>68$
2=>112$
3=>57$
```

Зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$users = DB::table('data_table_name')
       ->select(DB::raw('month_field, SUM(price_field) AS sum_field'))
       ->groupBy('month_field')
       ->get();
```

Ну или (что однофигственно)

```
       ->select('month_field', DB::raw('SUM(price_field) AS sum_field'))
```

Comment: Я всетаки не правильно сформулировал вопрос! У меня есть таблица `order` в таблице есть колонки `id`,`created_at`, `cost`. Нужно выбрать данные из таблицы таким образом,чтобы получилась сводка продаж по каждому дню. 
      1=>68$
      2=>112$
      3=>57$

Comment: Тогда `data_table_name=order`, `month_field=MONTH(created_at)`, `price_field=cost`. И соответственно и в `select`, и в `groupBy` надо использовать `DB::raw`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы спасли мои нервы и время)))